# eclipse (eclipse distribution/projects/workspaces) synched over several stations with Dropbox/SVN

Tags: eclipse, version-control, dropbox

I am trying to setup eclipse and the project/workspaces to works smoothly and efficiently over 3 different computers (not in the same LAN).

Right now I have to do this in every computer:

- install a plugin
- customize eclipse.ini
- customize prefs (I'll keep prefs.epf inside \eclipse folder and keep it synched with care)

I would like to avoid it so I won't end up with different versions of plugins etc in different computers. In order to achieve this, I have decided the following:

1. ***\eclipse distribution***

   I intend to put my \eclipse distribution under [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTQ5NzgyMjk). The reason for that is to use the exact same eclipse install in the 3 computers I use.
2. ***Projects***

   Projects (src and all resources etc) are synched by using SVN/Hg (I keep some projects under one, others in the other). No problem here. **But the same project is stored in different drive/path in different computers** (C:\projects\projectA and D:\projectA for example).
3. ***Workspaces***

   I use a different workspace for each project (or group of related projects). So I run eclipse with

   -data \path-to-.metadata

**My question is**, where do I put worskpace folders, and do I synch them?? I have two options:

- I keep workspaces inside Dropbox, this way they are synched automaticaly. But will it work?? As pointed out previously the same project can be in diff drive/path in two computers. This is the approach taken by [this stackoverflow guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157431/portable-eclipse), but not sure if he had diff. drives etc.
- I keep workspaces outside Dropbox, they are NOT synched. My question here is whether the same \eclipse will open -data \workspaceAInComputerA and then later open -data workspaceAInComputerB having both same names, projects etc but being totally separate workspaces.

It sounds a bit convoluted maybe but I think it's worth setting it right for long term usage. Anyone can recommend a setup?? 
thanks

ps: I don't want to keep taking a usb with me so don't suggest any 'portable eclipse' thing please!

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](http://blog.utahcon.com/computers/cloud-storage/dropbox-eclipse-awesome) seems to have put his workspaces in Dropbox and it seems to be working for him. Personally, I'm putting the Entire eclipse directory + some sdk's in dropbox - we'll see how that goes!

UPDATE: This went horribly wrong for me - just going to use svn/git