# Portable eclipse without java editor

Tags: eclipse, java

I need to work with eclipse Oxygen (or at least neon), and I do not have administrator rights on my pc. 
I downloaded a 64bits portable version of eclipe oxygen (photon) :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-neon-portable/

I'm using OpenJdk8 (JDK1.8) also in 64bits.

Here is my problem:
I start eclipse with the path of the 1.8 JDK, but I don't have Java editor.
Indeed I can't open Java view or create a Java project, even the Syntax highlighting colors for .java..

Does the problem come from the Eclipse editor? From the Jdk? From the Eclipse configuration?

I'm open to any new solution!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm working with the EMF editor and I need the Java one to edit compile the generated java code.

Comment: Found on the project page: `INSTALL NEW PROGRAMMING LANGUAGES: Just go to "Help" -> "Install New Software" and select your version by clicking the small arrow next to "Add".
Wait... Select your preferred entrys. Then click finish. That's it!`.

Comment: Yes I already tried that, in my case I have 3 repository adress and none of them works ("could not find http://..." 
And I can"t find the repository with the different langages. 

Also I search on eclipse market place some Java editors but I didn't find one, may be because it came by default with the eclipe java ide.

Comment: You should add what you have tried in your question then. Show us what you have tried, otherwise we'll spend time suggesting answers that you have already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Portable Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157431/portable-eclipse)